# Detect if string is beginning of valid python code

Tags: python, parsing, syntax

I have a string `s` which may be the beginning of a valid line of python. I would like a function which can determine that the string could be the beginning of a valid piece of python code or the string could not be due to syntactic errors.

Some examples of definitely invalid python strings:

- `def def`
- `def None`
- `def ()`
- `x = )`

These strings cannot be valid python code. They either use reserved words in inappropriate places or symbols in invalid contexts.

I have looked into [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) but it looks like it needs a full line of python. So `x =`  will fail even though it could certainly be the beginning of a valid line.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this issue using the library `parso`:

```py
import parso

def isValid(code):
  grammar = parso.load_grammar(version='3.9')
  try:
    module = grammar.parse(code, error_recovery=False)
  except parso.ParserSyntaxError as e:
    if e.args[1].token_type.name == 'ENDMARKER':
      return True
    else:
      return False
else:
    errors = grammar.iter_errors(module)
    if errors:
      return False

return True
```

Answer (score -1):

Use keyword module please find the link for your references  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list

```
    import keyword
    input_string="def"
    python_keyword=keyword.kwlist
    for key in python_keyword:
     if input_string in key:
        print("valid "+str(key))
```

Comment: NameError: name 'valid' is not defined

Comment: I have edited it it was string Sorry try now

Comment: Your code still fails the tests I stated in the initial post. "def" is a valid string. "def def" is also potentially valid. "def def " is invalid.